# Sort a deck of cards with minimum number of moves

Tags: algorithm

We have n cards with each card numbered from 1 to n.

All cards are randomly shuffled.

We are allowed only operation MoveCard(n) which moves the card with value n to the top of the pile.

We need to sort the pile of cards with minimum number of MoveCard operations.

The naive approach which i can think of is start with MoveCard(n), MoveCard(n-1), MoveCard(n-2).... MoveCard(1).

This approach will solve the problem in n MoveCard operations.

But can we optimize it.

For instance, If the input is like: 3 1 4 2

As per my approach:

```
                4 3 1 2

                3 4 1 2

                2 3 4 1

                1 2 3 4
```

MoveCard operations is 4.

But we can solve this problem with minimum number of moves:

Optimized solution is:

```
                3 1 4 2

                2 3 1 4

                1 2 3 4
```

MoveCard operations is 2.

From the optimized solution above, I am feeling the following approach will solve the problem.

Always we are picking the element to move which gives the sorted elements on the top and bottom with a condition the maximum element in the sorted sub array from the start should be less than the minimum element of the sorted sub array from the bottom.

In this case:

```
         3 1 4 2
```

Moving 2 we are getting 2 3 1 4 { 2,3 sorted from the start and 4 sorted from the bottom}

Now we are choosing 1 which gives the full sorted array. 1 2 3 4.

Comment: looks like a question for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should be moved to CS StackExchange.

Comment: don't know why people are downvoting . Looks like a good programming exercise .

Comment: @anon This is not a programming exercise, it is an algorithmic one.

Comment: @luk32: i meant something related to online judge programming :)

Comment: @luk32 I disagree. While this question does not contain code, it certainly does a good job of outlining the problem and expected output, along with including attempts made by the asker. That's better than many questions I see, and perfectly on-topic here. The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions algorithms as one of four bulleted topics.

Comment: @Geobits You disagree with what? That this is not a programming task? Implementing an algorithm is a programming task, not designing it. I am not saying that the OP did not put the effort.  I am not even saying the question is bad and should not be asked... but he is not specifying the language, nor has any specific problem regarding implementation. I am not saying it's plain wrong to ask here. I didn't down-vote it, I don't know why people did. I am saying there is a better place. SO and CS share topics of interests and this question fits better CS I share that opinion.

Comment: @luk32 I agree that it fits both sites, but to me that means it's fine *on either site*. I'm just saying it shouldn't be downvoted or closed here just because it might *also* be appropriate elsewhere. Many of the best quality (and highest voted) questions, particularly in the [algorithm] tag, don't specify a language or have a specific implementation problem showing. Apologies for targeting you specifically with the comment, it probably should have gone to one of the others.

Comment: Algorithms are an essential part of programming and if designing them isn't programming, we could easily teach computers to do all out programming for us, as it would mean programming was merely translating algorithms into code. Hence, I say: reopen.

Comment: @Geobits Probably because the only statement I made was that this is not aprogramming task =). Also I kind of share your view, it fits both sites currently. However I feel the problem is that SO grew so large that it split up into several other SE sites (CS, Programmers, etc.). I think most of high-vote questions are dated when there was no CS. I would also be not surprised if there was an action to mass move pure [algorithm] questions to CS at some point.

Comment: Also I think a nice way to flag and move questions fast to CS would be useful, it would place the question to a (debatably) better place in a painless way. This would spare the unecessary tension, debates, and rather unpleasant feeling of getting many down-votes, for a not such a bad question. Also please note, that there are questions asking about "Best" something, like the C++ book guide and they are kept for historical reasons. New questions like that are basically shot down. IMO a clear guideline on pure algorithmic questions is needed.

Comment: @luk32 There's a difference of opinions about that in Meta. You can see a couple discussions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97869/212780) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108695/212780), but they're a bit dated, so may not be taking the CS beta into account. You might be able to get a better consensus on the current state of things asking there. I agree it's fuzzy, but I'm not so sure that's a bad thing. I'm just gonna leave this here, since this comment chain is getting out of hand :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is looking at the numbers in reverse order. If the top two aren't in order, move the lower one. If they *are* in order, look for the next one down. After you find one not in order, move that one, and then each other card below it in descending order.

Basically, find `n`. If `n-1` comes *after* `n` in the array, move `n-1` to the front. `n--`, and repeat.

For example:

```
2 4 3 1    // 3 comes after 4, so move 3
3 2 4 1    // move 2
2 3 4 1    // move 1
1 2 3 4    // done after 3 moves

3 1 4 2    // 3 comes -before- 4, so leave it alone. 2 comes after 3, move it
2 3 1 4    // move 1
1 2 3 4    // done after 2 moves
```

It ends up being the same as the naive approach, but starting only with the "optimum" start. You don't always have to move the top cards.

Worst case time complexity is O(n^2), simply because you have to do an unordered search for each number. I can't prove this is the best complexity possible, but it's surely the simplest and clearest way to do it.

Worst case number of *moves* is `n-1`, since you can always just leave the `n` card alone.

Now, if you just want to know *how many* moves you need, instead of actually sorting, you can stop at the first move. For example, if you have to move `3` because it comes after `4`, then you'll need `3` moves. You can see this because if `3` is at the front, you'll *always* have to move every card below it to the front.